# What is the safest way to kill blazes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What is the most effective way to defeat blazes in Minecraft without taking any damage? If I attack them from a distance, they can easily set me on fire with their fireballs and take away 6-8 hearts of my health. Although I have tried using fire resistance potions, I still take some damage (1 heart) when they touch me. Do you have any suggestions on how to defeat them without losing any health?

Comment: Why do you not want to be harmed? Are you not able to heal?

Comment: Even with teh best armor, blaze will do more damange faster than natural healing. (Counting both ranged and melee damage plus fire damage) You best bet is potion of fire resistance.. and then keep a safe distance (majority of damage is fire based so melee shouldn't be able to kill you if you are not hungry)

Comment: You really get hit with their melee attacks? Use fire resistance, snowballs(they do damage), and hit them with a sword.

Comment: Blazes don't try to engage in melee on their own. With fire resistance you can shoot them point blank with a bow with complete impunity.

Comment: Oops, the edit summary should have also said "Made things a bit more concise".

Answer (score 21):

Use lots of snowballs. They do 1½ hearts of damage each to Blazes. If you can't make potions, diamond armor definitely helps with fire damage; iron does not work so well. Potions of fire resistance are a good idea though. If you can in the Nether, build some snow golems, though they wil probably get destroyed quickly.

Comment: Honestly, if you have a good source of snow this is the best way IMO.

Comment: and a good source of snow is 2 blocks of snow and a pumkin

Comment: If you enchant iron armor well enough, it can easily be as good as diamond armor.

Comment: I'm on my first attack against blazes...no fire resistance yet. Maybe I should put some fire protection on my armor and bring the equipment to build a little area to heal in with a snow golem for extra snowballs?

Answer (score 12):

Use Fire Resistance potions.

If you don't have access to them yet, make sure to stay at a long distance from Blazes and just shoot them with a bow.

Answer (score 8):

One of the easiest ways is to find a spawner (best to find a non open air one), rush towards it and seal it off at the enterance with blocks just before the stairs.

If you then remove the netherbrick one layer down at the base of your wall and remove the bottom blocks of your wall, you can happily chop away at their legs and they can't shoot you, nor can they get into where you are!

You may want to also knock out a few blocks behind you so you can move backwards if you need to. If you want exp, stay here as long as you want and collect stacks of blaze rods while you're at it.

Comment: This doesn't help with fighting blazes that don't come from a spawner, or spawners that are open to the air.

Answer (score 7):

You mean Blaze that drops Blaze Rod? Fire Resistance Potion will help a lot during battles with them. It will cancel out all the fire damages, leaving only physical damages caused by touching you. You can then stay at a distance and use arrow to shoot them.

Or, you could build a Blaze farm that wraps a Blaze Spawner with blocks and only leave one block for you to attack them.

Comment: Leave the opening at the floor level to avoid the blazes being able to attack through it.

Answer (score 4):

- Fire Resistance Potions
- Bow
- If you wait for them to fire their 3 fireballs there is then a pause before they can shoot again.

Some combination of these three should provide reasonable damage avoidance.

Comment: What about TNT!

Answer (score 4):

You should be wearing the best enchanted armor you have. You should also be drinking a potion of fire resistance before doing something like attacking blazes in the nether. Drinking a potion of healing would rapidly heal you when you are fighting them. The best armor would be diamond armor enchanted with either `Protection`, `Fire Protection`, or `Projectile Protection`.

In the overworld, you should gather snowballs and pumpkins. Then, you should go to the nether, make snow golems to attack the blazes. They receive three hearts of damage per snowball thrown, so they will be killed easily by seven snowballs. If snow golems attack too slow or melt too fast, you could do this yourself, although that would be less efficient because you would need to have many snowballs, and each stack only holds 16. You could also make iron golems to kill the blaze. This is also pretty inefficient because blazes can fly. However, if you give an iron golem a splash potion of healing, it could be used as a shield while you snipe the rest. Additionally, if you cover the whole place with cobwebs, they would still spawn, but would not be able to shoot fireballs as the cobweb blocks their fireball path.

If you can somehow get them to the overworld, they can take damage from water, such as water (the block), snow (if you are in a cold biome), or rain (if you are in a non-cold biome). You could also block them up with TNT, but that will ruin the terrain and possibly kill you.

Answer (score 3):

Find a spawner, then stand back from it -- they'll appear someplace near the spawner, so if you stand too close they'll drop on your head with a melee attack. Use an infinity bow so you won't have that "crap, out of arrows" moment, and keep a backup on hand in case it runs out of durability (or just keep an eye on the durability). As others have said, drink fire-resist potions so you won't be harmed by their ranged attack,and shoot rapidly, before they can close to melee. Keep some food on hand so you'll be sure to regen from the occasional hit and voila, all the blaze rods you can carry.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I do. For experts, skip to #3.

1. get a full set of at least iron armor and a iron sword (bow and arrows, optional).
2. go to the nether and get at least two blaze rods (you might get hurt during this step).
3. get magma cream from magma cubes if you don't have slime balls.
4. go home and craft one brewing stand and make  potions of fire resistance and strength potions, and add redstone to the potions to get the extended version > DO NOT TURN THEM INTO SPLASH POTIONS OR ADD GLOWSTONE !!!
5. go into the nether , drink the potions , and when you find the blaze , jump and strike them when you fall to hit them as hard as possible.
   (I got the achievement for dealing a blow of 9 hearts of damage!).

Anyway , this is what I do when I need things from the nether, just repeat steps 4-5 and that's it

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: The question says that fire resistance potions aren't good enough. Please inspect a question carefully next time before answering it.

Comment: Sorry but this is what I did and it did worked for me, and even if you didn't want the fire resistance because you lose materials, all you lose are materials that you will hardly ever use, and you will get hurt by blaze fires, ghast explotions and random fires throughout the nether, so your better of crafting that potion rather than going without it.

Answer (score 2):

Throw snow balls at them from up high.
it works great!

Answer (score 2):

I don't even bother with the armor. Fire resistance is a must and a diamond sword with knock back 2 at least. Keep moving and hit them right away. If you're lucky they mostly get knocked in the corner and you just keep hitting them.

Answer (score 2):

Find a spawner and make a little hut around it. Leave one block where you will be able to shoot your arrows through and voilà.

Comment: Note that the "little" hut has to be 8x8x3 to contain the spawnable area of a spawner. (If you're precise about it; otherwise 9x9x4 is safer.)

Answer (score 2):

If you are playing in Minecraft version 1.9 or above, [shields](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Shield) on your offhand can be helpful since they can block the Blaze's attacks.

Here's a short demonstration of shields in action (done on 1.16.1): [streamable video link](https://streamable.com/os6yeg)

Answer (score 1):

honestly people are making too much of a deal out of it and making it way harder! i dont use armour and i just use an iron no enchantment sword i build around the spawner so they cant just fly off and then i build it so ican just hit there legs but all they can do is fire things but they arent likely too and then boom ,,, xp and a stack of blaze rods!!

Answer (score 0):

build a nether portal right next to where you will be fighting blazes but far enough away that they wont "break" the portal. jump into the overworld and create a pond around the spawned portal. use this as escape and reduce fire damage. if possible have a full chest of healing potions and extra weapons and armor outside  the portal. this is how I did it and it worked great for me.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that since the Blaze can use a **LOT** of fire, <strike>drink a Fire Resistance Potion and</strike> wear armor with either, protection, Fire protection, or projectile protection so that you take less damage from the Blaze. It's also recommended to use snowballs, since they do a good amount of damage on the Blaze.

Answer (score 0):

My friend and I narrow doorways to keep blazes from mobbing us, then we take turns shooting at the blazes so the other person can heal.  This has been pretty effective for us.  Neither of us has died in the Nether in quite a while.

Answer (score 0):

Killing those first Blazes without potions is hard. I always dig myself down a block with overhead protection and go for their legs, limiting their capacity to hit you. This works well in a fortress corridor digging out the side a bit so there is only a narrow one block window for them to hit you through. After that, with potions it becomes a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

All I do is trap them so they can't hit you but you could hit their legs. I don't bother with the armor or the diamond sword. I use a iron sword and it still kills them quickly.
My friend stands behind me and throws snowballs at the blazes while I hit them from an angle. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's a really out of pocket solution. Splash Water Bottles (Water Bottles but splash potions), and Shields as those block Blaze projectiles. Once you close in, nail them with your strongest weapon. There's also Lingering Water Bottles (Water Bottles but with Lingering potion effects).
Otherwise, Snowballs.

Answer (score -1):

If you are with a friend one of you should attack with a bow and one of you should attack with a sword if you have punch on the bow it will be good because it will push the blazes back and the sword should have sharpness and knockback(not required) . It worked for me

Answer (score -2):

Just drink a potion of fire resistance then use TNT!

It's the best idea I could think of.

Comment: Fire resistance does not protect against TNT explosions and will ultimately kill you.